# Azure Table Storage: Order by

Tags: azure, sorting, azure-sql-database, azure-table-storage

I am building a web site that has a wish list. I want to store the wish list(s) in azure table storage, but also want the user to be able to sort their wish list, when viewing it, a number of different ways - date added, date added reversed, item name etc. I also want to implement paging which I believe I can implement by making use of the continuation token.

As I understand it, "order by" isn't implemented and the order that results are returned from table storage is based on the partition key and row key. Therefore if I want to implement the paging and sorting that I describe, is the best way to implement this by storing the wish list multiple times with different partition key / row key?

In this simple case, it is likely that the wish list won't be that large and I could in fact restrict the maximum number of items that can appear in the list, then get rid of paging and sort in memory. However, I have more complex cases that I also need to implement paging and sorting for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On today’ s hardware having 1000’s of rows to hold, in a list, in memory and sort is easily supportable. What the real issue is, how possible  is it for you to access the rows in table storage using the Keys and not having to do a table scan. Duplicating rows across multiple tables could get quite cumbersome to maintain.

An alternate solution, would be to temporarily stage your rows into SQL Azure and apply an order by there. This may be effective if your result set is too large to work in memory. For best results the temporary table would need to have the necessary indexes.

Comment: I am leaning towards doing the sort in memory and worrying about it later if it becomes a bottle neck.

Comment: ...your second suggestion is interesting however. Have you ever done anything like this? Transferring data between different storage would itself seem like something that would be slow.

Comment: I have not done this recently. Given that this is probably working in a disconnected world, and with scalability in mind across multiple instances, loading the result set, from table storage, to local memory for each request could be inefficient. Instead staging in SQL Azure would allow the data to be accessed from multiple instances after a single load.

On the other hand, if your implementation is based on a single instance with a limited data set, loading in memory could suffice. I would try the memory option first and then move to the SQL options if that does not work up to expectations.

Comment: I've gone with doing it in memory for the time being. I'm taking the [hopefully] pragmatic approach of getting it working and then worrying about optimizing for performance if/when it becomes a problem.

Comment: If you are working in Azure Storage table, jumping to SQL Azure is a huge hammer to be avoided.

Comment: The question is about ordering items in Azure Table Storage. If he has to stage all these data to SQL, then why shouldn't he just use SQL in the first place and avoid using Azure Table Storage

Answer (score 4):

Azure Storage keeps entities in lexicographical order, indexed by Partition Key as primary index and Row Key as secondary index. In general for your scenario it sounds like UserId would be a good fit for a partition key, so you have the Row Key to optimize for per each query.

If you want the user to see the wish lists latest on top, then you can use the log tail pattern where your row key will be the inverted Date Time Ticks of the DateTime when the wish list was entered by the user.
https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-design-patterns#log-tail-pattern

If you want user to see their wish lists ordered by the item name you could have your item name as your row key, and so the entities will naturally sorted by azure.

When you are writing the data you may want to denormalize the data and do multiple writes with these different row key schemas. Since you will have the same partition key as user id, you can at that stage do a batch insert operation and not worry about consistency since azure table batch operations are atomic.

To differentiate the different rowkey schemas, you may want to prepend each with a const string value. Like your inverted ticks row key value for instance woul dbe something like "InvertedTicks_[InvertedDateTimeTicksOfTheWishList]" and your item names row key value would be "ItemName_[ItemNameOfTheWishList]"

Answer (score 2):

Why not do all of this in .net using a List.

For this type of application I would have thought SQL Azure would have been more appropriate.

Comment: In the case of the wish list a list/IEnumerable may be appropriate, but I have other similar screens where there could be 1000's of results. I don't want to have to do all of that in memory. I am using Table Storage in favour of SQL Azure in this case because of the cost benefits.

Comment: Memory for 1000 rows isn't much at all. Also when you determine cost benefit you need to think about your time. If you are going to save an hour or more per month from using SQL Azure, it is far more cost effective to use SQL Azure. Unless you are dealing with BIG data and I mean huge, the cost benefits of Table storage over SQL Azure don't equate.

Comment: I gave you a plus +1.  It is not always about cost or size.  For a multi tenant application where you want separation of data creating a storage table is is easier and faster than creating database.

Answer (score -2):

Something like this worked just fine for me:

```
List<TableEntityType> rawData = 
    (from c in ctx.CreateQuery<TableEntityType>("insysdata") 
     where ((c.PartitionKey == "PartitionKey") && (c.Field == fieldvalue))
     select c).AsTableServiceQuery().ToList();
List<TableEntityType> sortedData = rawData.OrderBy(c => c.DateTime).ToList();
```

Comment: This will be sort the rows in memory

Comment: This ignores the original question including paging in scope, not just sorting.